# How can I show a flipbook as block in the front page?

Tags: 7, blocks

I've installed the FlipBuilder module that's created via the software  and can view the flipbook on its own url, but I want to put a copy of my flipbook on the front page, in its own block or in a panel, but I just can't successfully do this.

I have tried doing it with an iframe, but it says it's refused, perhaps to avoid x-frame issues.

Comment: What is flipbuilder? Is the module you're talking about [Flipbook](https://www.drupal.org/project/flipbook)? Maybe not, unless you meant to tag the post as `8` rather than `7`?

Comment: Ah - I spotted another question about [Flipping Book](https://www.drupal.org/project/flipping_book), which is probably what you meant?